# Prove that a topological space equipped with a delta-complex structure is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Suppose that $X$ is a topological space equipped with a delta-complex structure. Prove that $X$ is Hausdorff.

I can actually "see" why it should be Hausdorff after the hint from Hatcher asks to "think of a delta-complex X as a quotient space of a collection of disjoint simplices".

I would appreciate if somebody can write out a full formal argument showing this proof. I'm trying to start from the definition of Hausdorff but I don't know how to carry on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ra} [1] {\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ #1\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
 \newcommand{\da} [1] {\bigg\downarrow\raise.5ex\rlap{\scriptstyle#1}} $As you are using Hatcher's book, you will find in the appendix a section about CW-complexes, together with a proof that they are $T_4$. If you compare the inductive construction of a CW-complex with Hatcher's definition of a $\Delta$-complex, you will see they are pretty similar.

There is a major difference, though. The inductive process of building a CW-complex yields a quotient of a disjoint union of balls, whereas we would like to have a cell-complex structure on a given set $Y$. So we should have characteristic maps $\Psi_\alpha:D_\alpha^n\to Y$ which are injective on the interior, such that each point of $Y$ is in the image of exactly on such interior. We can then define the topology inductively on $Y$. Define $Y^n$ as the union of the images of $\Psi_\alpha$ up to dimension $n$. We assume that the restriction of each $\Psi_\alpha$ on the boundary of $D_\alpha^n$ is a continuous map to $Y^{n-1}$. We will show by induction over $n$ that $Y$ is homeomorphic to the quotient space of balls induced by these maps. It starts with $X^0$ which is the disjoint union of points $D^0$ and is homeomorphic to the discrete space $Y^0$. Assume now that $\Psi^n$ is a homeomorphism from $X^n$ to $Y^n$. Then the first arrow in the diagram is a homeomorphism.

$\large
\begin{array}{c}
X^n\sqcup\bigsqcup_\alpha D_\alpha^{n+1} & \ra{\Psi^n\sqcup\text{Id}} & Y^n\sqcup\bigsqcup_\alpha D_\alpha^{n+1}\\
\da{q} & & \da{\text{Id}\sqcup\bigsqcup\Psi_\alpha}\\
X^{n+1} & \ra{\Psi^{n+1}} & Y^{n+1}
\end{array}$

We will define $X^{n+1}$ as the adjunction space obtained by gluing the $D_\alpha^{n+1}$ along their boundaries to $X^n$ via $\phi(x)=(\Psi^n)^{-1}(\Psi_\alpha(x))$. So an identification takes place iff the images along the upper right path are the same. Since we topologize $Y^{n+1}$ as a quotient space, we get a homeomorphism on the bottom arrow.
This shows that $Y$ can also be considered a CW-complex although, as a set, it is not a disjoint union of balls.

So how can this be applied to a $\Delta$-complex? Well, take as $\Psi_\alpha$ the maps $\sigma_\alpha$. Property (ii) says that the restrictions are continous maps into the skeleton which exists by then, and property (iii) assures that the topology is the right one.

But a direct proof isn't difficult and would follow the idea of Proposition A.3 in the appendix. Assume by in induction that disjoint open neighborhoods $N^n(a)$ and $N^n(b)$ in the $n$-skeleton have been constructed. Then for a simplex $\Delta^{n+1}_\alpha$ there are four cases:

- $a$ and $b$ are in the interior of $\Delta^{n+1}_\alpha$: By Hausdorff there are disjoint open neighborhoods.
- $\sigma_\alpha^{-1}(a)$ is in the boundary and $b$ in the interior: By normality there are disjoint open $U,V$ with $\overline{\sigma_\alpha^{-1}(N^n(a))}\subset U$ and $b\in V$.
- $\sigma_\alpha^{-1}(a)$ and $\sigma_\alpha^{-1}(b)$ are both in the boundary: Then $\sigma_\alpha^{-1}(N^n(a))$ and $\sigma_\alpha^{-1}(N^n(b))$ can be "thickened" a bit towards the barycenter and remain disjoint.
- If one of $\sigma_\alpha^{-1}(a)$, $\sigma_\alpha^{-1}(b)$ is empty (Note that in this case also the corresponding $\sigma_\alpha^{-1}(N^n(-))$ is empty due to the way we construct the neighborhoods), then we can take the union with int($\Delta^{n+1}_\alpha$). If both are empty, there is nothing to do.

Doing this for every $n+1$-simplex yields the $N^{n+1}$'s, disjoint neighborhoods in the $n+1$-skeleton.

Comment: Is $T_4$ just another way of saying Hausdorff?

Comment: $T_4$ means normal and Hausdorff.

Comment: In your second bullet point, you said "By normality there are disjoint open...". Are we allowed to assume normality?

Comment: @HaikalYeo: A standard $n$-simplex is a normal space, since it is a metric space.

Comment: Am I right to say that there is meant to be a case of considering $a\in\Delta^{n+1}_\alpha$ and $b\in\Delta^{n+1}_\beta$ but because they are already in different indices, we can simply take the separate simplices to be the disjoint open neighbourhoods?

Comment: @HaikalYeo No, a simplex is not open. The interior could be open, but only if no higher dimensional simplex has it as its face. Note that "interior" here denotes the image of the interior (which is the standard-n-simplex minus its faces), but it doesnt mean the interior in the whole space.

Comment: Oh yeah indeed. But is the case of different indices still necessary or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @HaikalYeo: Ah, I see now that you meant that the interiors are the disjoint open neighborhoods relative to the $n+1$-skeleton. I will add the fourth case. Thanks for reminding me of that.

Comment: Ah yes. That's exactly what I meant. I'm sorry if that didn't come off as quite right but your answer says it in a much better way!