# $\Delta$-Complexes Are Hausdorff

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff

I am using the definition of a $\Delta$-complex as given in Hatcher's book  [here](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATch2.pdf) on pg 103.

Now on pg. 104, just before the section on Simplicial Homology, Hatcher remarks that if $X$ has a $\Delta$-complex structure then $X$ is Hausdorff.

I do not see it at all. Is this easy? Does anybody know of a reference where the general topological details of a $\Delta$-comlpex can be found?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at http://arxiv.org/abs/0809.4221, sections 2.4 and 4. In the section about realizations you can ignore the stuff about degeneracies/collapses, as that is only relevant for the more advanced *simplicial sets*. The way Hatcher defines what it means to equip a space $X$ with a $\Delta$-complex structure, this $X$ will be homeomorphic to the realization of the Delta-complex, so in showing that it is Hausdorff, you can deal with the realization as well.

Comment: Thank you. Also, do you know of an easy proof of the fact that a space $X$ with a $\Delta$-complex structure is Hausdorff? It shouldn't be too difficult since Hatcher doesn't even give a proof.

Comment: This question should be eventually closed as a duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375366/prove-that-a-topological-space-equipped-with-a-delta-complex-structure-is-hausdo?rq=1), once the bounty period is over.

Comment: Hatcher also proves that CW complexes are Hausdorff in one of the appendices, and every $\Delta$-complex is also a CW complex

Answer (score 1):

I am going through Hatcher now, stopped at the same point as you, and had the same question. I think I have a proof.

Let $p,q$ be distinct in $X$. By the definition of a $\Delta$-complex, we have that $\sigma_a(p')=p$ and $\sigma_b(q')=q$ for exactly one $a,b$ not necessarily distinct. Here, $\sigma_a:\Delta^n\to X$ and $\sigma_b:\Delta^{n'} \to X$.

Suppose $a$ and $b$ are distinct. Then by condition (i) in the definition of a $\Delta$-complex in Hatcher, $p'$ and $q'$ lie in interiors of different simplices. These interiors are disjoint and open in $\mathbb{R}^n$,$\mathbb{R}^{n'}$. Because $\mathbb{R}^k$ is Hausdorff, $p',q'$ lie disjoint neighborhoods open in their respective open simplices. The images of these disjoint open neighborhoods under $\sigma_a,\sigma_b$ are disjoint because of condition (i) in tandem with their being disjoint. And the images are open in $X$ because of condition (iii) in tandem with their being open. In particular, $p,q$ have disjoint open neighborhoods.

Now suppose $a$ and $b$ are not distinct. Then $p',q'$ lie in the interior of an $n$-simplex. This is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is Hausdorff, hence lie in disjoint neighborhoods open in the $n$-simplex. Then a more or less identical argument as before applies; the images under $\sigma_a$ of these open sets must be disjoint by (i), and must be open by (iii), hence we have found disjoint open neighborhoods of $p,q$.

I hope this is correct and helpful to whoever reads it. It does not seem like I actually needed to split this problem into cases.

---

As pointed out in comments, this proof is not correct. I will work on fixing it when I have time.

Comment: To be precise, the simplices $\sigma_a$ and $\sigma_b$ are only unique if you require that $p'$ and $q'$ are not in the boundary. You also use that requirement throughout the proof.

Comment: The image under $\sigma_a : \Delta^n \to X$ of an open subset of the interior of $\Delta^n$ is not necessarily an open subset of $X$: that image is open in $X$ if and only if $\text{image}(\sigma_a)$ is not a face of any higher dimensional simplex.